# error in command format hdfs

Tags: hadoop, format, hdfs

I install hadoop-0.20.2 and java-1.7.0 on centos. I've configured hadoop in the form below:

bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75/jre
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tasker</name>
<value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop-env.sh:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75/jre
```

When I run the following command would fail
command:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

Please help me.

Can anyone advise me?.....

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
$ /home/hadoop/opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```